# Mono is frequently used to say "Yes, .NET is cross-platform". How valid is that claim?

Tags: java, .net, mono

In [What would you choose for your project between .NET and Java at this point in time?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20255/what-would-you-choose-for-your-project-between-net-and-java-at-this-point-in-tim/20257#20257) I say that I would consider the "Will you always deploy to Windows?" the single most important technical decision to make up front in a new web project, and if the answer is "no", I would recommend Java instead of .NET.

A very common counter-argument is that "If we ever want to run on Linux/OS X/Whatever, we'll just run Mono"<sup>1</sup>, which is a very compelling argument on the surface, but I don't agree for several reasons.

- OpenJDK and all the vendor supplied JVM's have passed the official Sun TCK ensuring things work correctly.  I am not aware of Mono passing a Microsoft TCK.
- Mono trails the .NET releases.  What .NET-level is currently fully supported?
- Does all GUI elements (WinForms?) work correctly in Mono?
- Businesses may not want to depend on Open Source frameworks as the official plan B.

I am aware that with the new governance of Java by Oracle, the future is unsafe, but e.g. [IBM provides JDK's for many platforms](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/), including Linux.  They are just not open sourced.

So, under which circumstances is Mono a valid business strategy for .NET-applications?

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>[Mark H summarized it as](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/mono-is-frequently-used-to-say-yes-net-is-cross-platform-how-valid-is-that/20280#20280): "If the claim is that *"I have a windows application written in .NET, it should run on mono"*, then not, it's not a valid claim - but Mono has made efforts to make porting such applications simpler."</sub>

Comment: Also see http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/is-java-still-the-cross-platform-language-of-choice

Comment: Just to be clear, .NET is Microsoft's implementation of the CLI. Mono is a CLI implementation with Novell taking lead.

Comment: This sounds a lot more like an answer to the previous question rather than a question in its own right.  I would suggest you consider editing your question to make it stand more on its own.

Comment: @walter, the whole point is that I am aware of the usual "java is more cross-platform than .NET"-arguments, and I list them to make the answers incorporate the best possible counter-arguments.

Comment: Mono Compatibility -> http://www.mono-project.com/Compatibility ; Mono Roadmap -> http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap ; Mono Plans -> http://www.mono-project.com/Plans

Comment: "the single most important decision to make up front in a new web project" ... Actually, from a business standpoint, that isn't even in the top 10 of most important decisions to make up front for a new web project. From a technical standpoint, that's still a ways down on the list, and only comes into play based on where you're pulling your devs from. e.g. I live in a predominately C#/.NET town, so if I want to have access to that talent pool, I go with Windows.

Comment: @el fuser, always happy to learn more.  Which things would you put ahead on the list and why?

Comment: even before finishing reading the question i knew the answer marked as correct was going to be by Miguel de Icaza. lol. very good question.

Comment: @Red Dirt Software, I'd still like to hear what things you would put ahead on the list and why.

Comment: There's successful businesses built on all platforms... When planning a business and executing on that plan, the platform **rarely** comes into play... Especially for web projects.

Comment: @Red Dirt, if the platform is not in the top 10 list, what 10 decisions are then?

Comment: This is off-topic for the question. Head over to a business planning site and browse some sample plans to see what is **truly** crucial for a business... Tech X vs Tech Y is about as crucial as FedEx debating Ford vs. GM for delivery vans.

Comment: @Red Dirt, if we call it "single most _technical_ decision" are you happy then?

Comment: Not sure technical is the right description. Some places are just "Microsoft" shops and are going to build everything on this platform or they won't build it at all. An iPhone/Pad app decision will come from sales and marketing or the CEO wanting to maximize his holiday gift.

Comment: @JeffO iPhone/iPad is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: FYI, when you mention IBM Java, it should be noted that there are rounding differences vs. Oracle Java.  I forget if it's the Double class, the Float class, or BigInteger, but I remember some people being very surprised by this.

Comment: @user1249 - You missed the point. Focus on my first sentence and don't get caught up in the analogy.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

[Sparkie's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20275/mono-is-frequently-used-to-say-yes-net-is-cross-platform-how-valid-is-that/20280#20280) got it, let me complement a little.

".NET is cross platform" is too much of an ambiguous statement as both the framework and the world it was originally created for have changed and evolved.

The short answer is:

The underlying engine that powers .NET and its derivatives, the Common Language Infrastructure Standard, is cross-platform and as if you want to make your code go to multiple platforms, **you need to plan on using the right APIs on the right platform** to deliver the best experience on each platform.

The CLI family has not tried the "Write Once, Run Anywhere" approach, as the differences from a phone to a mainframe are too big.   Instead a universe of API and runtime features that are platform-specific has emerged to give developers the right tools to create **great experiences** in each platform.

Think of it: programmers no longer target Windows PCs or Unix Servers.   The world, now more than ever is surrounded by fascinating platforms from PCs, to gaming consoles, to powerful phones, to set-top boxes, to big servers and distributed clusters of machines.  **A one-size fits on all platform would merely feel bloated on tiny devices, and feel underpowered on large systems**.

The Microsoft's .NET Framework product is not cross platform, it only runs on Windows.  There are variations of the .NET Framework from Microsoft that run on other systems like the Windows Phone 7, the XBox360 and browsers through Silverlight, but they are all slightly different profiles.

Today you can target every major mainstream OS, phone, mobile device, embedded system and server with .NET-based technologies.   Here is a list that shows which CLI implementation you would use in each case (this list is not comprehensive, but should cover 99% of the cases):

- x86 and x86-64 based PC computers:

  - running Windows -> Typically you run .NET or Silverlight but you can also use full Mono here.
  - running Linux, BSD or Solaris -> You run full Mono or Silverlight
  - running MacOS X -> You run full Mono or Silverlight
  - running Android -> You run Mono/Android subset
- ARM computers:

  - Running Windows Phone 7: you run Compact Framework 2010
  - Running Windows 6.5 and older: you run the old Compact Framework
  - Android devices: you run Mono/Android
- PowerPC computers:

  - You run full Mono for full Linux, BSD or Unix operating systems
  - You run embedded Mono for PS3, Wii or other embedded systems.
  - On XBox360, you run CompactFramework
- S390, S390x, Itanium, SPARC computers:

  - You run full Mono
- Other embedded operating systems:

  - You run .NET MicroFramework or Mono with the mobile profile.

Depending on your needs the above might be enough or not.   You will hardly get the same source code to run everywhere.   For example, XNA code wont run on every desktop, while .NET Desktop software wont run on XNA or the phone.   You typically need to make changes to your code to run in other profiles of the .NET Framework.   Here are some of the profiles I am aware of:

- .NET 4.0 Profile
- Silverlight Profile
- Windows Phone 7 Profile
- XBox360 Profile
- Mono core Profile - follows the .NET profile and is available on Linux, MacOS X, Solaris, Windows and BSD.
- .NET Micro Framework
- Mono on iPhone profile
- Mono on Android Profile
- Mono on PS3 Profile
- Mono on Wii Profile
- Moonlight profile (compatible with Silverlight)
- Moonlight extended profile (Silverlight + full .NET 4 API access)

So each one of those profiles is actually slightly different, and this is not a bad thing.   Each profile is designed to fit on its host platform and expose the APIs that make sense, and remove the ones that do not make sense.

For instance, Silverlight's APIs to control the host browser do not make sense on the phone.   And shaders in XNA make no sense on PC hardware that lacks the equivalent support for it.

The sooner you realize that .NET is not a solution to isolating the developer from the underlying capabilities of the hardware and the native platform, the better off you will be.

That begin said, some APIs and stacks are available in multiple platforms, for example ASP.NET can be used on Windows, on Linux, on Solaris, on MacOS X because those APIs exist both on .NET and Mono.   ASP.NET is not available on some of Microsoft's supported platforms like XBox or Windows Phone 7 and is not supported either on other platforms that Mono supports like the Wii or the iPhone.

The following information is only correct as of November 21st, and many things in the Mono world will likely change.

The same principles can be applied to other stacks, a full list would require a proper table, which I have no idea of how to present here, but here is a list of technologies that might not be present on a particular platform.   You can assume that anything not listed here is available (feel free to send me edits for things I missed):

Core Runtime Engine [everywhere]

- Reflection.Emit Support [everywhere, except WP7, CF, Xbox, MonoTouch, PS3]
- CPU SIMD support [Linux, BSD, Solaris, MacOS X; Soon PS3,  MonoTouch and MonoDroid]
- Continuations - Mono.Tasklets [Linux, BSD, Solaris, MacOS, PS3, Wii]
- Assembly Unloading [Windows only]
- VM Injection [Linux, BSD, MacOS X, Solaris]
- DLR [Windows, Linux, MacOS X, Solaris, MonoDroid]
- Generics [some limitations on PS3 and iPhone].

Languages

- C# 4 [everywhere]
- C# Compiler as a Service (Linux, MacOS, Solaris, BSD, Android)
- IronRuby [everywhere, execpt WP7, CF, Xbox, MonoTouch, PS3]
- IronPython [everywhere, execpt WP7, CF, Xbox, MonoTouch, PS3]
- F# [everywhere, execpt WP7, CF, Xbox, MonoTouch, PS3]

Server Stacks

- ASP.NET [Windows, Linux, MacOS, BSD, Solaris]
- ADO.NET [everywhere]
- LINQ to SQL [everywhere]
- Entity Framework [everywhere]
- Core XML stack [everywhere]

  - XML serialization [everywhere, except WP7, CF, Xbox)
- LINQ to XML (everywhere)
- System.Json [Silverlight, Linux, MacOS, MonoTouch, MonoDroid]
- System.Messaging [Windows; on Linux, MacOS and Solaris requires RabbitMQ]
- .NET 1 Enterprise Services [Windows only]
- WCF [complete on Windows; small subset on Silverlight, Solaris, MacOS, Linux, MonoTouch, MonoDroid]
- Windows Workflow [Windows only]
- Cardspace identity [Windows only]

GUI stacks

- Silverlight (Windows, Mac, Linux - with Moonlight)
- WPF (Windows only)
- Gtk# (Windows, Mac, Linux, BSD)
- Windows.Forms (Windows, Mac, Linux, BSD)
- MonoMac - Native Mac Integration (Mac only)
- MonoTouch - Native iPhone Integration (iPhone/iPad only)
- MonoDroid - Native Android Integration (Android only)
- Media Center APIs - Windows only
- Clutter (Windows and Linux)

Graphic Libraries

- GDI+ (Windows, Linux, BSD, MacOS)
- Quartz (MacOS X, iPhone, iPad)
- Cairo (Windows, Linux, BSD, MacOS, iPhone, iPad, MacOS X, PS3, Wii)

Mono Libraries - Cross Platform, can be used in .NET but require manually building

- C# 4 Compiler as a Service
- Cecil - CIL Manipulation, workflow, instrumentation of CIL, Linkers
- RelaxNG libraries
- Mono.Data.* database providers
- Full System.Xaml (for use in setups where .NET does not offer the stack)

MonoTouch means Mono running on iPhone;   MonoDroid means Mono running on Android;   PS3 and Wii ports only available to Sony and Nintendo qualified developers.

I apologize for the lack of formality.

Comment: IBM, If you read this, I would like AIX (or even AS/400) to be on Miguels list!!

Comment: thanks for a definite, authorative (sp?) answer!

Comment: We know that IBM has done at least two ports of Mono to AIX, but the teams that did the port were not allowed to release the changes back.

Comment: +1 - This guy should be working on the Mono Project! Please don't take the bait ;)

Comment: +1 This makes me even happier to have a .NET job right now

Comment: @JeffO: This guy is the creator of Mono ;-)

Comment: @miguel.de.icaza I wonder have things changed since then? Maybe this answer requires a bit of a update or a link to a better source?

Answer (score 115):

First, you need to make a distinction between the Common Language Infrastructure (The open standard), and .NET (Microsoft's implementation of that standard). Mono is an implementation of the CLI, and has never claimed to be a "portable .NET". Also, the C# language is an open standard, and is not strictly tied to .NET.

I'm not aware whether Microsoft have any tool to validate that an implementation is compliant, but if they do, I'm pretty sure the mono guys have it, and use it.

Mono is trailing behind the .Net, but barely. Mono can run C# 4.0 code (current .NET version). Also, Microsoft have recently made all DLR code and libraries open source (under the Apache 2.0 license), which has enabled mono to make use of languages like IronPython, IronRuby, and F# has been made open source only last week. In addition, Microsoft are regularly releasing CTPs of upcoming features in .NET, which allows mono developers to keep up to date with current release versions.

There's a number of tools and extensions in .NET, for example, Code Contracts. These aren't always implemented fully in mono. (At present, I think there is a partial contract validator for Requires contracts). These aren't commonly used in .NET apps anyway, but if their popularity increased, so would the rate at which they get implemented in mono.

WinForms are not (entirely) portable. They are a .NET specific and not part of the CLI. The CLI does not specify any particular widget set. There are cross platform widget sets though (GTK# and Silverlight). If you were writing an application from the ground up with portability in mind, you would use one of these rather than Winforms/WPF. In addition, mono provides a thin wrapper for the Winforms API - which enables existing winforms apps to be ported more easily into GTK# (without entire rewrite).

Mono provides a tool, the Mono Migration Analyser (MoMA), which can take an existing .Net application and tell you about it's portability. (eg, identify unportable libraries that are used, P/Invokes etc).

For businesses that don't want to depend on Open Source - mono can be re-licensed. Ownership of code added to mono is handed over to novell, who can license it in alternative ways other than the usual LGPL license (which has very few restrictions anyway).

So as for the claim ".NET is portable", I think this can be a valid assertion if you are writing code from the ground up and are aware of the portability issues with the framework. If the claim is that "I have a windows application written in .NET, it should run on mono", then not, it's not a valid claim - but Mono has made efforts to make porting such applications simpler.

Comment: +1 for the last paragraph.

Comment: `the C# language is an open standard, and is not strictly tied to .NET.` and `C# 4.0 code (current .NET version)` are contradictory

Comment: Note that you can actually run a normal WinForms app in Mono, by using a Win32 emulator like Wine. I've seen a fairly complex WinForms app run fine on Linux using this trick

Comment: What I meant about it being not tied to .NET (or the CLI for that matter), is that there is no requirement for C# implementations to run on top of .NET - you could write a C# compiler which compiles to native code if you wish. The C# and CLI major versions are usually released alongside eachother, so what I meant is that mono supports the CLI 4.0

Comment: @Jader I think it means "what the current .NET version uses" because he's talking about C# 4.0, used by .NET 4.0.

Comment: @sparkie @Arda I know what sparkie meant. I was just being annoying.

Comment: One minor point: Winforms is 100% implemented now.

Comment: Your last point is a good one, and equally applies to Java. Just because you've coded your app in Java doesn't mean it's automatically portable to every platform that supports Java. Particularly for more complex projects, you find many Java applications have platform-specific code.

Comment: Besides all the Open Source code Microsoft has been release (such as MVC) that has allowed Mono to keep up, I know that Microsoft does help Mono by sharing their unit tests with them for some technologies, such as Moonlight, so that is sort of a "certification test" to pass all unit tests for a given technology/library

Comment: @Thomas Levesque, is that the Windows port of Mono you run in Wine?

Comment: @sparkie, the MoMA sounds very interesting for having an automatic test as part of the build process.

Comment: @user8057: Winforms is 100% implemented? Seriously? Check out the RichTextBox component. Check out drag and drop functionality on the Tree component. Swing is 100% cross-platform, on the other hand, though that might mean sucking on all platforms.

Comment: @Yar: LOL for "though that might mean sucking on all platforms" :-)

Comment: @Dean Harding  I've been working with Java for almost 10 years now (5 years after your post and 5 before), I (usually) develop on a Windows machine, then run builds/tests/deploy to Linux (to hotspot). I can't say in the last 10 years I've seen many (if any?) portability issues... I've only ever encountered 1 api (I've worked with at least a dozen others) that used native/Unsafe features and even that was 100% portable, pending correct installation of the native dlls/libs... I don't agree with your statement regarding java/j2ee portability at all, I think it's incorrect.

Answer (score 14):

Point by point:

- **OpenJDK and all the vendor supplied JVM's have passed the official Sun TCK ensuring things work correctly. I am not aware of Mono passing a Microsoft TCK.**
  There is a specification that the Microsoft CLR conforms to.  Mono is not a clone of Microsoft's CLR, but rather an implementation of that same specification.  On the one hand, there's the chance that this results in even greater incompatibility.  In practice, this has worked very well for mono.
- **Mono trails the .NET releases. What .NET-level is currently fully supported?**
  Because the documentation for .Net precedes the actual release, mono actually had completed (not a beta release) support for .Net 4 out *before* the official Microsoft release.  Additionally, mono does a very good job of documenting what things are not supported, and they have a few tools you can run against existing project to help you spot places with the potential for incompatibility.
- **Does all GUI elements (WinForms?) work correctly in Mono?**
  The vast majority of winforms works just fine.  WPF, not so much.  I've heard that the same is true for Java — many of the advanced widget/gui toolkits aren't as well supported on all platforms.
- **Businesses may not want to depend on Open Source frameworks as the official plan B.**
  If that's the case, they definitely won't be going with Java, then, as that puts an open source framework up even higher at plan A.

In summary, if you want to build a cross-platform app *right now*, there's nothing wrong with starting with mono from the get-go and using that as your framework.  You can even deploy mono on Windows if you want.

On the other hand, if you you're looking at building a Windows app today that you think *might* need to be cross platform at some unknown point in the future, you probably want to go with the native Windows widgets and tools.  .Net does a much better job here than does Java, and mono is a perfectly acceptable fall back in this scenario.

In other words: Yes, .Net if cross-platform in every way that matters to your question.  No, mono won't just run every .Net program out of the box, but your question is in the context of a new project. It doesn't take much work to keep new projects out of trouble and avoid compatibility issues, especially if you think in terms of developing for mono rather than developing for .Net.

Most of all, though, I think this is the wrong question in the first place.  Unless you're building a new development team from scratch, you're starting with programmers that have expertise in one area or another.  Your best results will be achieved by going with what your programmers already know.  As important as building a cross-platform app may seem, if you have a team full of .Net programmers with little java experience, you're unlikely to fire them or make them all learn java for your next project.  If you have a team full of java programmers, you're not gonna ask them to learn .Net for a Windows-only project.  Either of those would be nuts.

Comment: Just to clarify the "open source" issue:  I was thinking of an open source project as not being backed by a suable business entity, not as a business having a GPL'ed source code.

Comment: Novell is not “a suitable business entity”?

Comment: @svick - I don't think "suable" is typo. He's worried about legal issues surrounding the project's backers.

Comment: @Thorbj From a business perspective, it's better to have a strong supporting entity like Novell than an abstract entity like the JCP.

Comment: @user8057 Ah, I've never heard that word. It looked like a strange typo.

Comment: @user8057, correct.  And just to clarify, it is not _me_ that is concerned about the backing organization, but the businesses having to chose what to do.

Comment: @Joel: For your information, the JCP is an abstract entity because it's a nonentity. It exists only so long as Oracle wants it to exist. It makes recommendations about the Java platform, but all contributors to the JCP are signing agreements with Oracle, and Oracle owns all of the intellectual property.

Comment: FWIW, my company took a team of senior Java developers and had us develop a Windows app in .NET.  Certainly made more sense than laying everybody off and hiring new developers of unknown quality, especially given the short timeframe to deliver the product.  Just sayin'...

Answer (score 11):

I have worked with Mono, and I would say it is as good as you can get with an alternate platform that is open-source, and not directly supported by Microsoft.  If you can be comfortable using an *alternate open-source* platform like Clojure or Scala, you could probably be comfortable with using Mono.

The level of .NET supported by Mono can always be found on the [Mono Roadmap](http://www.mono-project.com/Roadmap) page.

Do all GUI elements work?  As far as I know, they do, although I haven't exhaustively tried every element.

Is Mono identical to .NET?  No.  I suspect there will be minor (and maybe major) tweaks required here and there.  You can't, at present, run the Entity Framework with it, for example.

Comment: Of course Mono isn't an exact clone but from what I've seen it is a very viable option when beginning new projects.

Comment: Is the character in you pic 美 me3i? from 美国?

Comment: @Jader, totally unrelated - but that's the chinese character for beautiful and 美国 (when combined means US, also literally means beautiful country)

Comment: AFAIK Clojure and Scala are languages not platforms. And (again AFAIK) Scala should run on any JVM implementation on which Java can run.

Answer (score 9):

**As a target, the .NET/mono universe *moves very fast*.**

Every few years, Microsoft comes out with some compelling changes and innovations regarding the language, runtime, and infrastructure surrounding .NET. For example: Generics, LINQ, DLR, Entity Framework -- with every new revision of Visual Studio, there's generally a pretty significant increase in the feature set and usefulness of the framework it targets.

While the constant improvement in the framework is welcome, it's also problematic if you want compatibility across multiple platforms. Long-term-support platforms like Red Hat Enterprise Linux move glacially slow with regards to adopting new technology, and at any given point, there's going to be significant improvements in the Mono platform that have happened just within the last few months. So if you want to run the stuff that the cool kids are building, you're going to have to compile Mono from scratch and manage your own patches and updates. That's not cool.

**Java, on the other hand, is as stagnant as a kiddie pool.** Especially now that it's own by a company that just wanted Java for the patent lawsuits, you can be fairly certain that there will be no detectable changes in the language or runtime in the foreseeable future. Java is as stable a platform as FORTRAN. That's not so good if you were hoping for any sort of improvements, but not so bad if you're trying to deploy an enterprise application.

Comment: Funny you mention Fortran, as it is evolving constantly with emphasis on concurency and parallazetion as well as OOP principles. So yes Fortran 77 is stable, but since Fortran 90 came out, each revision gets better and better. Fortran 2008 is "almost" a modern language.

Comment: I'd say that .Net/C# 1.0 was at best a poor Java clone, but by .Net 2.0 there was pretty good feature parity between the two platforms.  Going from there to .Net 3.5/C# 3, Microsoft's platform has left Java well behind in most areas and it continues to gain ground with new features like dynamic typing and upcoming features like async concurrency.  That said, one big reason .Net is able to move so fast is the trail left by Java. If Oracle wants to move Java forward they will be able to quickly follow the similar trail now left by Microsoft.

Comment: "the .NET/mono universe moves very fast". Ironically, the main reason we don't use Mono is that its GC development has been excruciatingly slow. They described the current stable GC as an "interim measure" in 2003! http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/mono-gc-list/2003-August/000012.html

Comment: Or you can just run Debian/Ubuntu, use a few external apt repositories, and play with the cool kids without compiling mono from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

From a user perspective, Mono sucks at making Windows .NET apps compatible with Linux. If you actually try to run any decently written Windows app in Mono it wouldn't work.

From a packager's perspective (I used to do a bit of work at PortableApps), .NET can be both a blessing and a curse. If you're only on Windows, .NET makes deployment a lot easier because more libraries means less system-dependent stuff (most notably between versions of Windows, I believe) but is also extremely confusing even on Windows because .NET versions are neither backwards-compatible or forwards compatible. You have to download different versions of .NET for different programs.

That said, Mono is a fine starting point for making C# programs cross-platform. Just don't package the program with the latest WINE and call it done though. Look where that took Picasa.

As with the two languages/platforms political stability, RMS would probably start ranting on about how Mono is headed by Novell, whose honeymoon with Microsoft is quite notorious. Both platforms can be considered politcally unstable right now.

If you really want easy cross-platform, the tried and true path is QT which is quite stable politically as of right now it's a) LGPL'd, b) done with its major licensing issues years past, and c) backed by Nokia, which sells really really popular phones.

Comment: How quickly things change. Nokia no longer sells phones people want, and Novell no longer exists with both Qt and Mono's future in doubt. This is probably the reason why businesses don't like using anything other than 'primary-supported' systems, like Microsoft. Which is why open source is such a good idea.

Answer (score 4):

Mono is not a 1:1 port of Microsoft's .net. There are technologies that Mono simply won't implement or has no plans to do so (e.g., Workflow Foundation or [WPF](http://www.mono-project.com/WPF)) while on the other hand they have some technologies of their own that Microsoft .NET doesn't do, e.g., SIMD Extensions.

Short Answer: Mono and Microsoft .NET are based on the same underlying foundation - CIL and BCL - but are separate projects.

Answer (score 2):

Small comment to the statements in the original post. I'll argue that the TCK remains a theoretical tool allowing Oracle to claim Java is an open standard. Because if you notice, Apache Harmony have been trying to get certified as "Java" for several years now, unsuccessfully. It's clear that Oracle really isn't interested in an open source implementation apart from the one they are affiliated with and more or less control (OpenJDK), which btw. much like Mono, is not complete (i.e. no Java Web Start support) and missing some optimizations available in the closed source HotSpot implementation.

So arguably, as of 2010; (most of) Java is open source but not an open standard, while (most of) .NET is not open source but an open standard. There are exceptions of course, the DLR, IronPython, IronRuby and F# actually are open source. Mono is interesting because it provides the best of both worlds, open source implementations of open standards.

Comment: The openness of Java is not the important part as such.  It is my experience that my programs run well on the JVM's that have passed the TCK so that is an important parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Putting all technicalities aside, a very important part takes place when actually writing the code.

As with any cross-platform technology (be it Java, Python, Ruby...), if the code is not written with portability in mind, you should assume there's basically zero chance the code  will run properly (even if such a chance is in reality much, much higher), as the odd misbehavior could be quite critical. Read: don't take the random assembly and run it under Mono.

Yet for a new project (or one you can refactor easily), choosing .Net/Mono as a potentially portable runtime makes sense, but you save yourself a lot of hassles by testing your code on Mono very early on, even if the project has only a slight change of going multiplatform. If you use a continuous integration server, this can be as simple as setting up a Mono build node. Many issues can be solved while developping, just by making a habit out of it (like building path strings) and a huge chunk of your code can be portable and unit-tested on Mono just by using sane practices and a little bit of forethought. The remainder (i.e failing unit tests) is then platform-specific (like code using PInvoke) but should be encapsulated enough so as to be able to provide an alternative implementation per targeted platform. This way when the project eventually comes to being ported a good part of the work has been done at almost no cost and the remainder is to be developped Just In Time.

Of course, using a library not available (.Net) or compatible (third party) in Mono precludes any of this, but *in my field* this has yet to be seen. That is the strategy we actually use at work, and when applying it I have no fear of claiming that .Net+Mono is cross platform.

Answer (score 0):

It varies is the honest answer.  I have seen small web server stuff moved from IIS to Apache, running under mono with almost no difficulty.  I have run unchanged Windows .Net applications using Win Forms on Linux successfully.

However, whilst it can work, if you are using an API call that's not implemented on mono then it won't work, and the only solutions are to either rewrite your application, stick with windows or write the extra stuff in mono.